# Stackoverflow when deserializing synchronizedSet from Hazelcast

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, stack-overflow, hazelcast

Consider the following code snippet to fetch/submit a Collections.synchronizedSet to/from Hazelcast:

```
IMap imap = getIMapFromHazelcastClient();
Set<UUID> mySet = (Set<UUID>)imap.get("someKey"); //This may trigger a stackOverflow, see below.
if ( mySet == null ){
    mySet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<UUID>());
}else{
    mySet = Collections.synchronizedSet(mySet);
}

//Concurrently add/remove elements from mySet

//After all concurrent operations complete, store the updated Set to Hazelcast.
//mySet should contain about 1-1.5K UUIDs at this point, every time.
imap.set("someKey", mySet);
```

After this code runs a few times (not sure how many, or why), the following is triggered in the attempt to get the Set from Hazelcast (marked above):

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2914)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2930)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3439)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:3497)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1242)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:800)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:991)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2017)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1895)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2202)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1712)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:519)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:477)
at java.base/java.util.HashSet.readObject(HashSet.java:344)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor564.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1226)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2401)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2235)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1712)

...About 900 lines of these
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2540)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2434)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2235)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1712)

at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2540)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2434)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2235)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1712)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2540)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2434)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2235)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1712)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:519)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:477)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:84)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:77)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)
at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:187)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.toObject(ClientProxy.java:102)
at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.get(ClientMapProxy.java:318)
...
```

In case it is relevant, both the application and Hazelcast (v3.12.9) run on the same JVM version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18) and on the same hardware. The same behaviour was observed when Hazelcast was running on v1.8.0 JVM.

The problem seems fixed after replacing the synchronizedSet with a simple HashSet in the storing part:

```
imap.set("someKey", new HashSet(mySet));
```

Obviously, storing a synchronizedSet in Hazelcast has no meaning, but is the stackoverflow justified somehow? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't recreate for me, full code before using Hazelcast 4.2-BETA-1. How is this different from your setup ?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String mapName = "so66579138";
        String key = "k";

        Config config = new Config();
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAutoDetectionConfig().setEnabled(false);
        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);

        HazelcastInstance hazelcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        
        IMap<String, Set<UUID>> imap = hazelcast.getMap(mapName);
        
        Set<UUID> mySet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<UUID>());
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 1500 ; i++) {
            mySet.add(UUID.randomUUID());
        }

        // PUT
        imap.set(key, mySet);
        
        // GET
        Set<UUID> mySet2 = imap.get(key);
        System.out.println("mySet2.size() == " + mySet2.size());
        System.out.println("mySet2.getClass().getName() == " + mySet2.getClass().getName());
        
        hazelcast.shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: I tried some combos, 3.12.9, Java 8, Java 15, above is just the 4.2-BETA-1 version

Comment: Thanks for the response Neil.
Unfortunately, I do not have a specific pattern to reproduce the issue.
The key difference is that my code may be executed multiple times before crashing not just once as in your code. And also that the synchronizedSet is altered by mutliple threads and is created (initialized) by using the Set received from Hazelcast, in case this is relevant.

Comment: Also, consider my code a method that is accessed concurrently by multiple threads( but for a different key for each thread).

Comment: So could it be concurrent access to the synchornized set while serialization is occurring?

Comment: No, all concurrent read/write operations to the synchronizedSet complete before submitting to Hazelcast.

Comment: Understood. When you retrieve a `mySet` from Hazelcast that isn't null, is it always a synchornisedSet that is returned ? If so, is `Collections.synchronizedSet(mySet);` needed ? Ie. attempting to apply synchronizedSet to a synchronizedSet . Or if it's not that type when retrieved, what type of set is it ?  Can you print the class for instance to confirm.

Comment: Yes, it is always a SynchronizedSet and ofcourse re-applying to one is redundant and an oversight from my side.
So, since the SynchronizedSet wraps the given collection with a new Object, probably after calling this code a few (maybe thousand) times,I believe justifies the stackoverflow.
Thanks for your help Neil!